# mongodb auto index future collections, big json size, correct structure?

Tags: database, mongodb, database-design, bigdata, database-administration

We are going to index some data in mongodb (probbably), from some api calls sending json data ~10MB size, splited data in dates.

Since the data is large, I think it's better to split the result in collections for each day data and have documents in each collection.
We need indices on some documents in each collection also.
documents will be updated in 15 minutes interval if the data changes(like prices or new entries)

Questions:

1. Is the structure I mentioned something efficient for the search?
2. Is there any other database with more performance on this type of data and size that could be administered as simple as mongodb?
3. If we use same structure, is there any way to set indices on newly created collections (for upcoming days) without scripting or adding manually? (like a unique index on DB that will apply on all collections and documents inside)